# PHP one form to post to two tables while getting the id of the first table posted to

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I am using Cakephp2.0 
I have a table for all my images and a table for features.

I have a form that takes the following inputs:
name of feature
text and multiple images with image name.

I need to insert the feature name and text into the feature table, grab id just created, and insert it along with all the image info from the form. I am not sure how to make the controller do that.

controller:

```
 public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Feature->create();
        if ($this->Feature->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Feature has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'dashbords', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your Feature.'));
    }
}
```

form:

```
<?php   
    echo $this->Form->create('Feature', array(
            'class' => 'form-horizontal',
            'role' => 'form',
            'type' => 'file',
            'inputDefaults' => array(
                'format' => array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'error', 'after'),
                'div' => array('class' => 'form-group'),
                'class' => array('form-control'),
                'label' => array('class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'),
                'between' => '<div class="col-lg-6">',
                'after' => '</div>',
                'error' => array('attributes' => array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-inline')),
            ))); ?>
    <?php
        echo '<fieldset>';
        echo '<legend>Add Features</legend>';

        echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">';
        echo $this->Form->input('Feature.name', array('class' => 'feature')); 
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="col-md-8">';
        echo ''; 
        echo '</div></div>';
        echo '</fieldset>';
        //----------------------- Image Block -----------------------------//   
        // group main image //
        echo '<fieldset>';
        echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">';
        echo '<legend>Main Image</legend>';

        echo $this->Form->input(
                'upload', array(                    
                        'type' => 'file',
                        'class' =>'main_image')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('Image.name', array(
                                'class' => 'main_image')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('placement_id', array(         
                                'type'  => 'hidden',
                                'value' => '1',
                                'class' => 'main_image'));      
        echo '</div>';

        // bottom left image //
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        echo '<legend>Bottom Left</legend>';
        // group image 2//
        echo $this->Form->input(
                'upload', array(                    
                        'type' => 'file',
                        'class' =>'bl')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('Image.name', array(
                                'class' => 'bl'));

        echo $this->Form->input('placement_id', array(         
                                'type'  => 'hidden',
                                'value' => '2',
                                'class' => 'bl'));
        echo '</div>';

        // bottom right //
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        echo '<legend>Bottom Right</legend>';

            echo $this->Form->input(
                'upload', array(                    
                        'type' => 'file',
                        'class' =>'br')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('Image.name', array(
                                'class' => 'br')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('placement_id', array(         
                                'type'    => 'hidden',
                                'value' => '3',
                                'class' => 'br'));      
        echo '</div></div>';
        echo '</fieldset>';

        //----------------------- Gallery Block -----------------------------//     
        // group 1
        echo '<fieldset>';
        echo '<legend>Gallery</legend>';
        echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">';     
        echo $this->Form->input(
                'upload', array(                    
                        'type' => 'file',
                        'class' =>'gallery1')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('Image.name', array(
                                'class' => 'gallery1'));

        echo $this->Form->input('placement_id', array(         
                                'type'  => 'hidden',
                                'value' => '4',
                                'class' => 'gallery1'));
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        // group image 2//
        echo $this->Form->input(
                'upload', array(                    
                        'type' => 'file',
                        'class' =>'gallery2')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('Image.name', array('class'=>'gallery2'));

        echo $this->Form->input('placement_id', array(         
                                'type'  => 'hidden',
                                'value' => '4',
                                'class', 'gallery2'));

        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        // group image 3 //
        echo $this->Form->input(
                'upload', array(                    
                        'type' => 'file',
                        'class' => 'gallery3')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('Image.name', array('class'=> 'gallery3')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('placement_id', array(         
                                'type'  => 'hidden',
                                'value' => '4',
                                'class', 'gallery3'));      
        echo '</div></div>';
        // Feature Text //
        echo '</fieldset>';     
        echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><fieldset>';
        echo '<legend>Content</legend>';
        echo $this->Form->textarea('Feature.content', array('rows' => '10', 'cols' => '75'));       
        echo '</fieldset></div></div>'; 
    ?>
</fieldset>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10">
        <?php echo $this->Form->end('Save Content'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modles:
Featuer:

```
class Feature extends AppModel{
    public $useTable = "features";
    public $displayField = "name";

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Image'=>array('classname' => 'Image', 'foreignkey' => 'image_id'),

    );
}
```

**Update:**
Per @SverriM.Olsen I have done some more research. I have concluded a few things like how to upload multiple images. Which then lead me to the fact I did dont know how to allow for a name to use as the image alt tag, so I removed that and in my controller add function I looped through the array and grabbed the file name minus the extension. I have read about set and saveAssociated. Where I am at now it how to join the newly created array of names and add then to the image table with the images from the form. here is an updated controller:

```
 public function add() {
        //get array of images loop throug 
        $file = $this->request->data['Image']['image'];

        // get file name and extract name - extention 
        $name = array();        
        foreach($file as $key=>$value){
            foreach($value as $k=>$v){
                if($k == 'name'){
                    $file = $v;

                    $info = pathinfo($file);
                    $file_name =  basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);                   

                    $this->set(
                            'Image', array(
                                'name'=> $name[] = $file_name));                        
                }
            }
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Feature->create();

            if ($this->Feature->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {             
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Feature has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'dashbords', 'action' => 'index'));                
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your Feature.'));
            debug($this->Feature->validationErrors);            
        }
    }
```

and an updated form (add.ctp)

```
<?php   
    echo $this->Form->create('Feature', array(
            'class' => 'form-horizontal',
            'role' => 'form',
            'type' => 'file',
            'inputDefaults' => array(
                'format' => array('before', 'label', 'between', 'input', 'error', 'after'),
                'div' => array('class' => 'form-group'),
                'class' => array('form-control'),
                'label' => array('class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label'),
                'between' => '<div class="col-lg-6">',
                'after' => '</div>',
                'error' => array('attributes' => array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-inline')),
            ))); ?>
    <?php
        echo '<fieldset>';
        echo '<legend>Add Features</legend>';

        echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">';
        echo $this->Form->input('name'); 
        echo $this->Form->textarea('content', array('rows' => '5', 'cols' => '55'));    
        echo '<br/><br/>';
        echo '<div class="col-md-8">';
        echo ''; 
        echo '</div></div>';
        echo '</fieldset>';
        //----------------------- Image Block -----------------------------//   
        // group main image //
        echo '<fieldset>';
        echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">';
        echo '<legend>Main Image</legend>';
        echo '<p>Uploade multiple image for each lug set at once.</p>';

        echo $this->Form->input(
                'Image.image.', array(              
                        'type' => 'file',
                        'multiple' => 'multiple',
                        'class' =>'main_image')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('Image.name', array(
                                'type'  => 'hidden',
                                'class' => 'main_image')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('placement_id', array(         
                                'type'  => 'hidden',
                                'value' => '1',
                                'class' => 'main_image'));      
        echo '</div>';

        // bottom left image //
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        echo '<legend>Bottom Left</legend>';
        // group image 2//
        echo $this->Form->input(
                'Image.image.', array(                  
                        'type' => 'file.',
                        'multiple' => 'multiple',
                        'class' =>'bl')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('Image.name', array(
                                'class' => 'bl'));

        echo $this->Form->input('placement_id', array(         
                                'type'  => 'hidden',
                                'value' => '2',
                                'class' => 'bl'));
        echo '</div>';

        // bottom right //
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        echo '<legend>Bottom Right</legend>';

            echo $this->Form->input(
                'Image.image.', array(                  
                        'type' => 'file',
                        'class' =>'br')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('Image.name', array(
                                'class' => 'br')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('placement_id', array(         
                                'type'    => 'hidden',
                                'value' => '3',
                                'class' => 'br'));      
        echo '</div></div>';
        echo '</fieldset>';

        //----------------------- Gallery Block -----------------------------//     
        // group 1
        echo '<fieldset>';
        echo '<legend>Gallery</legend>';
        echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">';     
        echo $this->Form->input(
                'Image.image.', array(                  
                        'type' => 'file',
                        'class' =>'gallery1')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('Image.name', array(
                                'class' => 'gallery1'));

        echo $this->Form->input('placement_id', array(         
                                'type'  => 'hidden',
                                'value' => '4',
                                'class' => 'gallery1'));
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        // group image 2//
        echo $this->Form->input(
                'Image.image.', array(                  
                        'type' => 'file.',
                        'class' =>'gallery2')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('Image.name', array('class'=>'gallery2'));

        echo $this->Form->input('placement_id', array(         
                                'type'  => 'hidden',
                                'value' => '4',
                                'class', 'gallery2'));

        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        // group image 3 //
        echo $this->Form->input(
                'Image.image.', array(                  
                        'type' => 'file.',
                        'class' => 'gallery3')); 

        echo $this->Form->input('placement_id', array(         
                                'type'  => 'hidden',
                                'value' => '4',
                                'class', 'gallery3'));      
        echo '</div></div>';
    ?>
</fieldset>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10">
        <?php echo $this->Form->end('Save Content'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help or pointer to places that will help is great. I will try some more googling.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html) thoroughly?

Comment: add your model relationship code

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen - I have been looking it over I am still new to cake and trying to understand it.

Comment: please don't be shy you put your whole application here

Comment: instead of adding all my coder here is a link to my app on git https://github.com/KKM-Clients/FacePlateSeries-Dashboard